# Cannot Update Record in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've created this table in PostgreSQL and every time I try to update it, I get this message:

> Perhaps you meant to reference the column "product.id"

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the table and the `UPDATE` statement:

```
drop table if exists product;
create table product(
    id       serial ,
    name     varchar(30),
    price    varchar(30),
    qty      varchar(30)
);

update product 
   set name='amir', price='dds', qty='eee' 
where id =1;
```

Comment: Are you trying to update a record that doesn’t exist? 

Comment: That statement will not result in that error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af6bd4ec530768d29ec590546d7550dc

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Are you using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=42b33906391f55ed26cd0fa369640329) (or trying to)?

Comment: Why do you have `price` and `qty` as `VARCHAR`s? Surely they're numbers of some sort? Maybe you're in an industry with which I'm not familiar and these are standard codes? But, if you're using PostgreSQL, then you should (probably) be using TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you’ve structured the table and your question, I’m going to assume this is your first foray into databases. Welcome!

The `UPDATE` statement will only work if you have data with matching criteria in the table already. If you are adding records, you want `INSERT`.

Let’s build your table, with a few updates:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    id       serial,
    name     varchar(30),
    price    decimal(16,2),
    qty      int
);
```

Now we’ll add a record:

```
INSERT INTO Product (name, price, qty)
VALUES ('Widgets', 15.99, 400);
```

Now you can query the table:

```
SELECT * FROM Product;
```

This will give you the record that was just created. To update the price, now you can use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Product
   SET price = 9.77
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Querying the table again will show the new price:

```
SELECT * FROM Product;
```